# NameError: global name 'TkVersion' is not defined in Winpython 2, but not in IDLE2

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

Tkinter does not appear to work anymore in Winpython, but it runs ok in Python 2.

strange problem and I cannot figure it out.
I have Python27 installed in F:\Python27 and I have
Winpython2 installed in F:\Winpython\python-2.7.5.amd64

My program worked out of winpython2 yesterday, and I do not know why I decided to open this sample
http://tkinter.unpythonic.net/wiki/tkFileDialog
in IDLE 2.
and it works great in IDLE 2. (but now not in Winpython)

I originally used this 
http://effbot.org/zone/tkinter-directory-chooser.htm

and as stated above - both samples ran in my Winpython environment.

Current status: I open the sample
http://tkinter.unpythonic.net/wiki/tkFileDialog

I get error in Winpython:

```
File "<stdin>", line 1, in 'module'
  File "F:\WinPython\python-2.7.5.amd64\lib\site-packages\spyderlib\widgets\externalshell\sitecustomize.py", line 523, in runfile
     execfile(filename, namespace)
  File "F:\OneDrive\Programming\Python\_workingCode\InlineColorPilot\Tkinter2.py", line 2, in 'module'
     import Tkinter, Tkconstants, tkFileDialog
  File "Tkinter.py", line 3, in 'module'
     class TkFileDialogExample(Tkinter.Frame):
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Frame'
```

If I run:

http://tkinter.unpythonic.net/wiki/tkFileDialog

I get error in WinPython

```
     return apply(Chooser, (), options).show()
   File "F:\WinPython\python-2.7.5.amd64\lib\lib-tk\tkCommonDialog.py", line 20, in __init__
     if TkVersion < 4.2:
 NameError: global name 'TkVersion' is not defined
```

Comment: Hi, I just opened pynche from the F:\winpython\python-275\Tools\pynche directory and that works.

Comment: I downloaded a new WinPython version with the same issue

Comment: This python script works:
#!/usr/bin/env python      
import Tkinter as tk       
import tkFileDialog

class Application(tk.Frame):              
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master) 
        self.dir_opt = options = {}
        options['initialdir'] = 'C:\\'
        options['mustexist'] = False
        options['parent'] = master
        options['title'] = 'This is a title'
        
        tkFileDialog.askdirectory(**self.dir_opt)
        
app = Application()                       
app.master.title('app')    
app.mainloop()

Comment: I had a Tkinter.py file that I created - but I deleted it.